# Перегрузка конструктора с переменным количеством параметров и неявное преобразование типов данных

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, function-overloading

В общем, у меня есть класс матриц.

```
C++
class matrix
    {
    private:
        int name;
        int M, N;
        double *array;

    public:
        matrix(); //по умолчанию

        matrix(int);                        //конструктор для инициализации нулевой квадратной матрицы
        matrix(int, int, const double*);    //конструктор для прямоугольной матрицы с заданным массивом
        matrix(int, int, double, ...);      //конструктор для прямоугольной матрицы с заданными элементами double
        matrix(int, const double*);         //конструктор для квадратной матрицы с заданным массивом
        matrix(int, double, ...);           //конструктор для квадратной матрицы с заданными элементами double
        matrix(int, int, const initializer_list<double>&);
        matrix(int, const initializer_list<double>&);

        matrix(const matrix &);             //конструктор копирования
        matrix(matrix &&);                  //конструктор перемещения

        ~matrix(); //деструктор

    //-------------функции-элементы класса------------------------//
    int getCols() const;
    int getRows() const;
    int getName() const;
    bool ifMulti(const matrix&) const;
    bool ifAdd(const matrix&) const;
    double findMIN() const;
    double findMAX() const;

    //-------------операторы-элементы класса------------------------//
    matrix operator += (const matrix &);
    matrix operator -= (const matrix &);
    matrix operator *= (const matrix &);
    matrix operator *= (double);
    matrix& operator = (matrix &&);     //оператор перемещения
    matrix& operator = (const matrix &);

    //класс для перегрузки оператора []//
    class Row
    {
        const matrix& A;
        int I;
    public:
        Row(matrix& a, int i) : A(a), I(i) {}
        Row(const matrix& a, int i) : A(a), I(i) {}
        double& operator[](int);
        const double& operator[](int) const;    //для константных матриц

    };

    Row operator [](int);
    const Row operator [](int i) const;         //для константных матриц

    //-------------дружественные функции------------------------//

};
matrix operator + (const matrix&, const matrix &);
matrix operator - (const matrix&, const matrix &);
matrix operator * (const matrix&, const matrix &);
matrix operator * (const matrix&, double);
ostream& operator << (ostream &, const matrix &);   //вывод
```

Конкретно проблема в этих двух конструкторах:

```
matrix::matrix(int n, int m, double arr, ...) : N(n), M(m), name(c_name++)      //конструктор для прямоугольной матрицы с заданными элементами double
{
        array = new double[N * M];
int i = 0;
for (double *p = &arr; i < N * M; p++)
{
    array[i] = *p;
    i++;
}
cout << "\n//Вызван КОНСТРУКТОР матрицы " << name;
}


matrix::matrix(int n, double arr, ...)  : matrix(n, n, arr)     //конструктор для квадратной матрицы с заданными элементами double
{
    cout << " (квадратной)";
}
```

и если в main вызвать что-то вроде:

```
matrix D(3, 2, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0);
matrix E(2, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 , 4.0 );
```

то компилятор будет ругаться на матрицу Е:

> E0309 существует более одного экземпляра конструктора
>   "mathObj::matrix::matrix", соответствующего списку аргументов:    ...

и будет ссылаться на те два конструктора, т.е. компилятор выбрать не может какой-то из них.

//явно объявлять тип не помогает:

```
matrix E((int)2, (double)1.0, (double)2.0, (double)3.0 , (double)4.0 );
```

С этим можно что-то сделать? о:

Comment: У вас конструктор является функцией с переменным числом аргументов? Никаких преобразований типов данных тут не видно. Вообще следует привести [полноценный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `for (double *p = &arr; i < N * M; p++)` - это еще что такое? Откуда это лезет постоянно? Кто вас учил так работать с `...` аргументами?

Comment: Просто выровняйте количество параметров в перегруженных конструкторах и компилятор тогда Вас поймет. Например `matrix(int n, int m, ...) ` и `matrix(int n, double arr,  ...) `.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: О каком "правильно" вы ведете речь? В VS2017: "error C2666: 'matrix::matrix': 2 overloads have similar conversions / while trying to match the argument list '(int, double, double, double, double)'"

Comment: @AnT Я вообще то не Вам отвечал, ну да ладно. Специально для Вас: https://onlinegdb.com/Hkyn7sPK4

Comment: @Andrey Sv: У нас тут на SO нет такого понятия как "не вам отвечал", Пожалуйста, не замусоривайте комментарии подобными ремарками. Что касается вашего примера по ссылке: он сильно и принципиально отличается от примера в вопросе - вы убрали параметр `arr` из первого конструктора.

Comment: @AnT Чем это отличается? Что Вам непонятно? "вы убрали параметр arr из первого конструктора" - именно это и предлагается сделать, прочитайте комментарий.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: Я ясно написал ниже, чем это отличается - тем, что в вашем примере количество фиксированных параметров *одинаково*. Это принципиально меняет ситуацию и делает код компилируемым. Самое удивительное, что вы сами (!) упоминали это в комментариях ранее. А теперь вы вдруг уже не видите, "чем это отличается"??? O_o

Comment: @AnT  Я то как раз все вижу. предложил решение: "Просто выровняйте количество параметров в перегруженных конструкторах и компилятор тогда Вас поймет. Например matrix(int n, int m, ...) и matrix(int n, double arr, ...)  ", которое наглядно демонстрируется [здесь](https://onlinegdb.com/r1jfOiDYN). если Вам по какой то причине это решение не нравится, обоснуйте это.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: Не понял. Вы задали конкретный вопрос: "А чем Вы компилируете интересно так как в VS2017 все вызывается правильно". Какое отношение этот вопрос имеет к вашему решению???

Comment: @AnT Человек удалил свой комментарий. где указал,что некорректно работает перегрузка после выравнивания аргументов, на который я и ответил. Вас это ввело в заблуждение, так как мой ответ остался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно преобразовать функции с переменным количеством аргументов в шаблоны c переменным количеством параметров:

```
template<typename... x_Cells>
matrix(int n, int m, x_Cells... cells)

template<typename... x_Cells>
matrix(int n, x_Cells... cells): matrix{n, n, cells...}
```

Размерность матрицы я бы тоже вынес в качестве параметра шаблона.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант -

```
matrix(int n, int m, initializer_list<double> arr);
matrix(int n, initializer_list<double> arr);
```

и вызывать как

```
matrix D{3, 2, {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0}};
matrix E{2, {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 }};
```

Так не пойдет?

Comment: такие конструкторы уже есть. если с тем вариантом не разберусь, видимо, оставлю только эти %)

Comment: @a1rltt Они есть, но они проблемные. Если вы ошибетесь с количеством (или даже типом!) параметров, отстрелите себе ногу. Да и вообще, проход по `...` руками вместо встроенных функций - неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Неоднозначным в вашем примере является только вариант

```
matrix E(2, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 , 4.0 );
```

С точки зрения процесса разрешения перегрузки, вторая функция является лучшим кандидатом для второго аргумента: там наблюдается точное совпадение `double -> double`, в то время как для первой функции требуется преобразование `double -> int`.

Но в то же время первая функция является лучшим кандидатом для третьего аргумента: там наблюдается точное совпадение `double -> double`, в то время как во второй функции имеет место "слабое" соответствие `double -> ...`.

В результате получаем неоднозначность.

Не рекомендуется смешивать перегрузки по типу и по `...` при разном количестве фиксированных аргументов. Особенное если учесть, что даже преобразование `double -> int` в С++ имеет более высокий ранг, чем `double -> ...`.

---

Что это такое?

```
for (double *p = &arr; i < N * M; p++)
{
    array[i] = *p;
    i++;
}
```

Такого в языках С и С++ нет. Работа с `...` аргументами ведется только через `<stdarg.h>`, `va_list`, `va_start` и так далее.

Если бы вы не занимались подобной ерундой, вы смогли бы просто не именовать параметр `arr` в некоторых случаях, тем самым сделав количество фиксированных параметров одинаковым. Именованные аргументы (`n` и `m`), с которых можно начать `va_start` в ваших функциях уже есть.

---

Отдельно можно добавить, что не ясно, как вы собрались реализовывать неконстантный доступ к матрице в классе `matrix::Row`, если ссылка на матрицу в этом классе у вас жестко "прошита" как `const matrix& A;`